# How do I instantiate and consume a DLL library in C#

Tags: c#, dll, vb.net-to-c#

I have a DLL library that contains data and string functions, among other things.  I've used it in VB.NET applications like this:

```
Private Shared _ll As LLUtils.LLUtils
_ll = New LLUtils.LLUtils("param1", "param2")
```

But I can't figure out how to do it in C#.  I get that I have to declare it as a static class, but it only has the one constructor, which requires parameters, and I can't figure out how to do that in C#.  I have this:

```
private static LLUtils.LLUtils _ll;
```

But I can't figure out the rest.  I tried running it through Telerik's converter, and it gave me endless errors.

Comment: `_ll = new LLUtils.LLUtils("param1", "param2");`?..

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to C#.  I've been doing VB.NET for so long that switching syntax is making me dizzy.  Sorry if it was a dumb question.